# Not getting a response from wait_read_frame()

Tags: python, xbee

I can't get the python-xbee library to receive a response from my remote router.  They're connected.  The local Xbee is a Coordinator API, the remote is a Router AT.

It doesn't seem to be a connection issue because I can use XCTU to send and receive remote packets without a problem.  I'm using Series 2 Xbees.

I added a class to help parse the serial responses.  It prints out fine for local 'at' commands, but all 'remote_at' commands hang, with no response printed.  I can issue a remote_at command (without waiting for a response) and it is processed correctly by the remote XBee.  Issuing the remote command hangs at wait_read_frame().  I've tried waiting a few minutes, but it's just stuck.

I'm trying to query the D1 input pin and get its status back (high `\x05`, low `\x04` or off `\x00`)

Here's the code I've been using to debug.  What am I doing wrong?

```
from xbee import XBee
import time
from serial import Serial

PORT = '/dev/ttyAMA0'
myRouter = 'a big long hex string...'

def message_received(data):
  print data

class TappedSerial(Serial):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TappedSerial, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def read(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data = super(Serial, self).read(*args, **kwargs)
    print ("read: ", repr(data))
    return data

  def write(self, data, **kwargs):
    print("wrote: ", repr(data))
    return super(Serial, self).write(data, **kwargs)

def main():

  tapped_ser = TappedSerial(port=PORT, baudrate=9600)
  xbee = XBee(tapped_ser) #, callback=message_received)

  try:

    xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter, command='D1', options='\x00')
    response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
    print(response)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

  finally:
    tapped_ser.close()
    print("exiting program")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed setting up the library:

1. In the version I checked out, in base.py line 74, the code to start the background thread if the callback was set is commented out.  Since you got read requests, I don't think that's your issue, but keeping in in case anyone else gets here with a similar problem.  You can call xbee.start() manually to make the thread run.
2. I found that enabling python logging was a bit more useful than the tappedSerial in this case - I enabled logging by adding the following at the top:

   ```
   logger = logging.getLogger()
   logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   ch = logging.StreamHandler()
   ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
   logger.addHandler(ch)
   ```

This revealed that I was adding 4 bytes to my ND responses because I had NO set to 3 instead of 0.  I'll send a pull request that appends the DD value to parameters if it's defined, as determined by the length being off by 4.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: You need to include a frame_id with the packet.  From John Foster's [XBee Cookbook](http://www.science.smith.edu/~jcardell/Courses/EGR328/Readings/XBeeCookbook.pdf):

> Byte: frame id. This is an arbitrary value chosen by the host. The value will be returned in the response packet,
>   except that a value of 0 will suppress the response packet.

Adding a frame_id to the packet gets a response back.  Any arbitrary character (other than 0) works.

```
   try:
    xbee.remote_at(dest_addr_long=myRouter, command='D1', frame_id='A')
    response = xbee.wait_read_frame()
    print(response)

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: Nevermind.  This gets a response back from the XBee, but it only prints out the response through the TappedSerial class that I'm using.  The XBee library still hangs.